# updates to very large SP lists

Tags: list, 2016, excel

I have an Excel sheet with 200K rows and I want to replace it with a SharePoint 2016 list, since Excel files in SP don't allow for simultaneous editing by multiple users. Ideally I would create a custom form for a user to look up an entry by ID, as well as content queries that show the most recent entries. Although SP lists are capable of millions of rows, will server performance be affected with what I'm proposing?

Comment: SharePoint on-premises does support co-authoring for Excel files, assuming everyone is using the Excel web app: https://docs.microsoft.com/SharePoint/governance/co-authoring-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-the-end-user-experience-of-co-authoring-in-sharepoint-server

Comment: Thanks. To my knowledge, all the users have the Excel client application instead of the web app.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2016, you can store about `~30,000,000` items per list, However, you should think about the `List view threshold` that was increased in SharePoint 2016 to be greater than `5,000` items.

> Read more about [**SharePoint 2016 List and Library Limits**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-list-and-library-limits/)

Regarding the `List view threshold`, you will get this error in case, the list items become more than 5000 items

> Microsoft put a threshold or a limit to not retrieve more than 5000 items or files at a time in a single view

However, you can overcome this limitation by following the instruction mentioned in this article [**Manage large lists and libraries**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

> You may also like to read [**SharePoint 2019 Limitations**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2019-limitations/)

Comment: Does the list view threshold apply to queries as well, where the user is looking for a single item?

Comment: The list view threshold will be applied In case, the retrieved items are more than 5000 items!